# Is it a good idea create all the routes when my application starts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node.js in my new web app and I create all the routes when my application starts. Does it affect my application in a positive or negative way?

For example, I have several routes:

```
app.get('admin/1', controller.1);
app.get('admin/2', controller.2);
app.get('admin/3', controller.3);
app.get('admin/4', controller.4);
app.get('admin/5', controller.5);
```

When the user requests a route the controller will be loaded, right?

So I made this little function that will create all the routes when the application starts.

The code above will be as follows:

```
registerRoute(app,
    [
        ['GET', '/admin/1', controller.1],
        ['GET', '/admin/2', controller.2],
        ['GET', '/admin/3', controller.3],
        ['GET', '/admin/4', controller.4],
        ['GET', '/admin/5', controller.5],
    ]
);
```

I think this is more organized, but I want to how this will affect my app.

Thanks!

---

Update:

Example:

```
registerRoute(app,
    [
        ['GET', '/admin', mainController.index],
        ['GET', '/admin/events', eventController.index],
    ]
);
```

And the registerRoute code:

```
var registerRoute = function (app, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        createRoute(app, arr[i]);
    }
};

function createRoute(app, arr) {
    if (arr[0] === 'GET') {
        createGET(app, arr);
    }
    ...
}

function createGET(app, arr) {
    app.get(arr[1], arr[2]);
}

module.exports = registerRoute;
```

**This is an example for the GET verb.**

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're really asking here?  Can you show us the code for `registerRoute()` if that's what you're asking about it?  Also, `controller.1` is not legal Javascript syntax.  Identifiers cannot start with a number.

Comment: Yes i can... just a sec @jfriend00

Answer (score 1):

Nope... Express or any other frameworks.  Will form a table of routes in the start of the application . what you are trying is just creating wrapper for creating routes... So there is no difference there